# Как сделать счетчик, с прокруткой цифр по разрядам reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, counter

Всем привет.
Есть счётчик цифр с анимцией.
Первая анимация начнется через 10 секунд
[Вот пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-counter-zs1pkj?file=/src/App.tsx)

Нужно сделать так, чтобы числа прокручивались по разрядам (возможно это называется по другому).

То есть, если число изменилось например на 254, 
то десятки прокрутились 5 раз,
 сотни прокрутились 2 раза, 
а единицы прокрутились 54 раза.

И все с разной скоростью, десятки и сотни медленно, а единицы быстро

Число изменяется каждые 10 секунд. Оно может быть и 10 000 000

Для этого в компоненте есть пропс cycle.

Ещё проблема в том, что я не знаю как сделать, чтобы когда цифра прокручивается вниз, нужно как-то массив с цифрами скопировать и вставить его вверх, чтобы с имитировать прокрутку колеса множества раз.

Надеюсь понятно объяснил. Заранее спасибо за ответы

Comment: В вашем текущем варианте ошибка. `Value` не передан

Comment: Да, извиняюсь, не заметил. Обновил ссылку